# MS Teams Online Meeting - User Principal is visible in Participants on Upadating OnlineMeeting

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

**Issue -** User Principal is visible as participant in Participants after updating OnlineMeeting.
See below Screenshot -
[image]

**Logic used to update the onlineMeeting**

- Create Event with OnlineMeeting - no user added at this point

```
    var eventObject = new Event()
    {
        Start = DateTimeTimeZone.FromDateTimeOffset(startTime),
        End = DateTimeTimeZone.FromDateTimeOffset(endTime),
        Subject = request.Subject,
        IsOnlineMeeting = true,
        OnlineMeetingProvider = OnlineMeetingProviderType.TeamsForBusiness
    };
    
    var  e = await _graphClient.Users[UserPrincipalName]
             .Calendar.Events.Request().AddAsync(eventObject);
```

- Get UserPrincipalId

```
    var userPrincipalFilter = $"userPrincipalName eq '{userPrincipalName}'";
    
    var userPrincipalById = _graphClient.Users[userPrincipalName].Request()
        .GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Id;
```

- Get the OnlineMeeting for event using JoinWebUrl

```
    var meeting= _graphClient.Users[userPrincipalId].OnlineMeetings.Request().Filter(meetingFilter).GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult().FirstOrDefault();
```

- Update the created Event

```
        OnlineMeeting meetingUpdate = new OnlineMeeting()
    {
                    LobbyBypassSettings = new LobbyBypassSettings()
                    {
                        Scope = LobbyBypassScope.Everyone,
                        IsDialInBypassEnabled = true
                    },
                    IsEntryExitAnnounced = true,
                    AllowMeetingChat = MeetingChatMode.Limited,
                    RecordAutomatically = false,
    };
    var updatedMeeting = _graphClient.Users[userPrincipalId].OnlineMeetings[meeting.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(meetingUpdate)
    .ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

- To Get the online meeting uisng JoinWebUrl, we had to add policy to 'Allow application to access online meetings on behalf of serviceprincipal email'.
  Followed steps from link ['Allow application to access online meetings on behalf of user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/manage-skype-for-business-online-with-microsoft-365-powershell?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: Please add more details about the user that was added. When creating an event what's the value of UserPrincipalName? When updating an event what's the value of userPrincipalId? How did  you get meeting.Id? Now it's hard to reproduce the issue.

Comment: updated questions with how I got userPrincipalId.